# Qual a diferença na declaração de variáveis utilizando const?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, declaração-de-variável

No [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) foram adicionadas algumas funcionalidades, dentre elas está o `const` que pelo visto é utilizado da mesma forma que o `var`, para declarar variáveis.

Qual a diferença entre variáveis declaradas utilizando este `const` ou não?

Comment: Caramba, eu tinha procurado umas três vezes e não encontrei nada, essa busca do StackOverflow tá meio ruim ^^

Comment: Mas na verdade existe uma pergunta entre `let`e `var`. Não abrange o `const`. Seria isso duplicado ainda? E o Const?

Comment: Não consigo encontrar nenhuma pergunta no site que se refira ao que significa o `const`. @Maniero ♦

Answer (score 0):

Bom, fundamentalmente falando, o `const` serve não somente para definir que a variável tenha o escopo global, mas principalmente para tornar o valor da variável imutável, para que não possa ser alterado e por causa disto, ter um valor constante.

## Explicações

## Modificador `const`

Como alguns já conhecem de outras linguagens, o `const` se refere a palavra `constante` o que significa imutável ou sempre igual. O escopo do `const` em questão é um escopo global, assim como se não houvesse `let` nem `var`. Por isso a razão de existir este modificador não é para fins de escopo e sim devido ao fato que uma variável declarada como `const` se torna imutável, resultando em um erro qualquer tentativa de atribuição à ela. Porém há duas exceções, caso o valor da variável `const` seja um objeto, você ainda poderá alterar o valor dos atributos de tal objeto, porém o objeto permanece imutável, você não pode atribuir outro objeto à ela. Também serve para Array's, você pode adicionar mais elementos ao Array atribuido a ela, mas não pode atribuir outro Array a ela.

#### Exemplo

```
VARIAVEL_GLOBAL_COMUM = 0;
const MINHA_CONSTANTE = 1;

MINHA_CONSTANTE = 2; //Isso resulta em um erro. Você não pode alterar o valor de uma constante.
VARIAVEL_GLOBAL_COMUM = 3; //OK.

var MINHA_CONSTANTE = 4; //Resulta em erro porque você não pode utilizar o mesmo nome reservado para uma constante definida.
let MINHA_CONSTANTE = 4; //Resulta em erro porque você não pode utilizar o mesmo nome reservado para uma constante definida.

const OBJETO_CONSTANTE = { atributo: 'texto' };

OBJETO_CONSTANTE = { outroAtributo: 'texto' }; //Resulta em erro. Você não pode atribuir outro objeto para a constante já definida.
OBJETO_CONSTANTE.atributo = 'Outro Texto'; //Funciona. Porque você pode alterar o valor do atribuito dentro do objeto já atribuido.

const ARRAY_CONSTANTE = [1,2];

ARRAY_CONSTANTE = [1,2,3]; //Erro. Você não pode atribuir outro Array para o array constante já definido.
ARRAY_CONSTANTE.push(3); //Funciona. Você pode adicionar um valor no Array já atribuido na constante.
```

Perceba que o modificador `const` não é utilizado para fins de escopo diferente e sim para congelamento de variável, mas tendo em vista que é possível receber um Objeto que pode ter o valor de seus atributos alterados e um Array que pode ter mais elementos adicionados.

## Conclusão

O `const` tem um escopo global, assim como declarar uma variável sem modificador, mas a principal função dele é tornar variáveis imutáveis.

#### Fontes/Referências:

- [MDN: const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)